# 'IN' clause in mysql making the execution slower, is there any other choices?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table named 'language' as shown below

```
personid |     lang
-------------------
1       |    english
1       |    french
1       |    italian
2       |    italian
3       |    french
3       |    italian
4       |    japanese
```

I wish to select all personid's with any of the language that personid 1 know.
(That is, any personid which have values english, french or italaian)

I have used the following query and got the solution. But it seems little bit slower. (I think it's due to 'IN' clause). Is there any other query option for faster execution.

```
SELECT distinct personid FROM language WHERE personid!=1 AND lang IN (SELECT lang FROM language WHERE personid=1)
```

Comment: Please let us know if any query helped speed up your process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self-join of the `language` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l2.personid AS personid FROM
language l1 INNER JOIN language l2
ON l1.lang = l2.lang
WHERE l1.personid = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+
| personid |
+----------+
|    2     |
|    3     |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT distinct personid 
FROM language AS l1
WHERE personid != 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM language AS l2
                                WHERE personid = 1 AND l1.lang = l2.lang)
```